# Remove favicon completely

Tags: browser, favicon

I don't have any icon for my site and i'm planning to remove it completely. Can I make it look like the icon doesn't exist at all and move the text over to the left where the icon starts? This should work in all 3 browsers.

Comment: which is the site and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's a company internal site so I can't tell you which one it is but I haven't seen any promising leads so haven't tried anything. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently no way to obtain this:

[image]

However, you can get this by creating a fully transparent favicon:

[image]

This said, the result is a bit odd and might surprise some of your visitors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was almost certain that this was the case but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing out on something I don't know.